# Restore default actionbar layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I apply a custom `View` to the `ActionBar`, like this

```
// Inflate the "Done/Discard" custom ActionBar view.
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) DetailsHost.mActionBar
        .getThemedContext().getSystemService(DetailsHost.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
final View customActionBarView = inflater.inflate(
        R.layout.actionbar_custom_view_done_discard, null);

// Show the custom ActionBar view and hide the normal Home icon and title.
DetailsHost.mActionBar.setDisplayOptions(
        ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM,
        ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME
                | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
DetailsHost.mActionBar.setCustomView(customActionBarView, 
        new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

(based on Roman Nuriks code).

How do I restore the initial layout? Note: I use ActionBarSherlock

Answer (score 29, accepted):

### Show/hide custom actionbar view

Since you only added a custom view to the bar without removing the title it should be sufficient to hide that custom `View`. You can use method `setDisplayShowCustomEnabled()`. Just call:

```
getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(false);
```

And enable home functionality again:

```
getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

*(Note in all code examples use `getSupportActionBar()` instead of `getActionBar()` if you're using actionbar compat. Also the `getActivity()` is only needed from fragments, in activities refer to the activity itself, in most cases `this`)*

### Restore actionbar title

If however you also removed the title when creating your custom view you'll have to enable that again also.

```
getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
```

### Restore completely

You can also call the setDisplayOptions() method with a combination of options to reconfigure the actionbar in one call. The below example removes the custom view and shows the title.

```
getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(
    ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
```

See [Android API docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayOptions(int)) for more details on these options.

Comment: This let the title and icon vanishing. Any ideas how to get them back? `mActionBar.setTitle();` doesn't work.

Comment: `DetailsHost.mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);` and `DetailsHost.mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);` enable them again.

Comment: Yes, that will work. Also, you can use `DetailsHost.mActionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME |  ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);` instead of calling those three methods.

Comment: In my case it's `DetailsHost.mActionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE | ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP);`,  I need to enable the up button as well. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Yes, right. I updated the answer to contain the missing pieces.

Comment: This did the trick. Annoying we need to set DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME and setDisplayShowHomeEnabled... I guess you get granular control and only need to call setDisplayShowHomeEnabled to show/hide later on...

Answer (score 2):

```
ActionBar actionbar;

actionbar = getActionBar();

Button cls = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_close);

cls.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){           
    public void onClick(View view){
       actionbar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(false);                
   }            
});
```

Note:
    The button with id 'btn_close' was located in the custom actionbar layout.This function was written in mainactivity.

Hope this Helps!!