# ActionBarSherlock - dividers not showing pre-ICS

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm trying to implement a cancel/done layout in my action bar using ActionBarSherlock by adapting the code found [here](https://plus.google.com/113735310430199015092/posts/R49wVvcDoEW).

Everything works as intended on ICS or Jelly Bean (where ABS will use the native ActionBar). When testing on Gingerbread (API 10), everything works fine except that the divider does not appear between the buttons:

[image: Gingerbread-missing-divider]

I at first thought that this was an issue with the divider image, but even when using code like:

```
android:divider="#f00"
```

No divider appears on Gingerbread, but a bright red one appears, as expected, on ICS/JB. Apparently ActionBarSherlock 3.5+ uses the native behaviour for divider appearance, so why is the divider not appearing when ABS is used but is appearing when the native ActionBar is used?

Here's my XML:

**actionbar_custom_view_done_discard.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="?attr/dividerVertical"
    android:dividerPadding="12dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:showDividers="middle" >

    <include layout="@layout/actionbar_cancel_button" />

    <include layout="@layout/actionbar_done_button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**actionbar_cancel_button.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/actionbar_cancel"
    style="?actionButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/abs__item_background_holo_light" >

    <TextView
        style="?actionBarTabTextStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_cancel"
        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:text="@string/action_cancel" />

</FrameLayout>
```

**actionbar_done_button.xml** is exactly the same as the above but with the name, text and icon changed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dividers in `LinearLayout` are API 11+. This has nothing to do with ActionBarSherlock.

You can simply add a 1dp view with a background between the two elements to work around this.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I'll just do that then.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I've found to be the best implementation of the custom `ActionBar` layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<include layout="@layout/actionbar_cancel_button" />

<!-- View below is used because the android:divider attribute only works on API 11+. This is identical in appearance to that. -->

<View
    style="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionButton"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:background="@drawable/abs__list_divider_holo_light" />

<include layout="@layout/actionbar_done_button" />
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, this is cleaner than my View. Maybe post the whole LinearLayout as I did so that people can copy & paste

Comment: It's actually from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15390898/2044848) answer which used the native implementation in the layout-v11 folder and a custom one in the layout folder. It worked, but I felt like it was unnecessary duplication. I'll edit my answer to include the entire layout. The button layouts are described in my question.

Comment: could you post the layout code for one of you actionbar buttons? thanks